# How Button below added fragment in Relative layout are clickable

Tags: android, android-layout

I am adding a fragment in a relativelayout dynamically. In my relative layout there are some buttons 
already there .
When adding a fragment in layout ,buttons are not displayed , means hidden , but clicking on 
buttons position click event is called. How ?

To solve this issue i am simply enable and disabling the button on attach and on detach of fragment

The code for adding a fragment

```
private void showMiscOptions() {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();

    if (mMiscFragment != null && mMiscFragment.isAdded()) {

        fragmentTransaction.show(mMiscFragment);

    } else {

        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.order_container, mMiscFragment);

    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    mFragNamLabel.setText("Add Item");
}
```

My point is how the event is getting called when there is no button visible
please refer images also

[image]

Picture of added Fragment 
[image]

When my fragment is added in layout , and buttons are not visible but clicking on those red
areas of fragment calling the events of buttons behind that .

Comment: How are you hiding them?

Comment: No , i am not hiding them . I am just adding the fragment in relative layout. as button view are not visible it should be not clickable right ?

Comment: Is Hiding only way to , or enabling disabling only way to solve this issue. and why the button touch is called ?

Comment: You are doing something wrong because it should not be clickable. Maybe someone will help if you post some more code of your fragment and the way you are adding it to this container (RelativeLayout).

Comment: i have edited my code can you look now

Answer (score 6):

I know I'm late to answering here, but you need to set the main layout of your "Enter Item Price" layout to have the `clickable` property set to `true`, so that it absorbs clicks on it instead of transferring them to the underlying fragment.

Answer (score 0):

For a situation like this you should be using two different `Fragments` with two different layouts. The problem may be with: `fragmentTransaction.show(mMiscFragment);` but I would need to see more code to know exactly what you are doing