# Shouldn't there be an option for Fragments to retain click events within their view hierarchy?

Tags: android, android-fragments

After seeing a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166554/how-button-below-added-fragment-in-relative-layout-are-clickable) questions here on SO regarding `Fragments` "passing" their click events down to clickable `Views` in underlying `Fragments`, I recalled that I once encountered this problem. What is actually happening is that if a user clicks on a blank area of the top most `Fragment`, since its `ViewGroup` is not clickable, the event will be handled by the clickable `View` (i.e. `Button`) that is conveniently placed just below the user's finger.  I fixed it by making the top `Fragment`'s `ViewGroup` clickable. Back then I didn't give it much thought, but this solution seems a bit "hacky".

I understand that it is normal behavior for a `View` that is non clickable by default to not intercept click events, but one would think that given that one big use for `Fragments` is to display the view hierarchy (a task done by the `Activity` only before) that it will resemble an `Activity` in this sense. When one `Activity` fires the `Intent` to create a new `Activity`, and then this `Activity` is on the screen, no click events are delivered to the underlying `Activity`. I realize that an `Activity` can contain many `Fragments` that may not fill the whole screen or even have no xml, but sometimes click events are only meant to be retained by the top most `Fragment`.

With all that said, here come the questions:

1) Is setting the `ViewGroup` on the top most `Fragment` to be clickable the best way to solve this?

2)  Does this feature exist and I am not aware of it? And if not, should it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is setting the ViewGroup on the top most Fragment the best way to solve this?

Assuming that your UI is akin to the UI from the question you linked to, the UI is written improperly.

My take on the UI from that question is that the developer has two fragments, A and B, each of which fill the screen. A is there initially, with the three buttons at the bottom. The developer then calls `add()` to display B, where B has an opaque black background.

This is dumb on a few levels. Not only do you run into this touch event propagation issue, but you have overdraw problems, because Android is going to render the buttons, then render the black background on top of them.

The right answer here is to have B `replace()` A.

(I realize that the developer actually does not have a fragment A, but has those widgets in the activity, which adds another level of sketchiness to that UI)

More generally, I would not have fragments, or anything else, higher on the Z axis with the intent to *hide* underlying widgets. So, for example, having a full-screen `VideoView`, with a pop-up `MediaController` higher on the Z axis is fine, because touch events destined for the controller would be picked up by the controller, yet the user can still tap on portions of the `VideoView` not blocked by the controller. Conversely, I would not implement a tabbed Web browser by having one `WebView` overlay another `WebView` on the Z axis -- either there would only be one `WebView`, or there would only be one *visible* `WebView` (with the other removed from the view hierarchy or marked as `View.GONE`).

> When one Activity fires the Intent to create a new Activity, and then this Activity is on the screen, no click events are delivered to the underlying Activity.

That is because there is no "underlying activity" in terms of the view hierarchy. More technically, each activity is in its own `Window`, and so even if the top-most `Window` does not fill the screen (e.g., dialog-themed activity), the "underlying activity" is visible but cannot receive touch events.

> I realize that an Activity can contain many Fragments that may not fill the whole screen or even have no xml, but sometimes click events are only meant to be retained by the top most Fragment.

Then there should not be anything underneath "the top most Fragment", IMHO. Use `replace()`, not `add()`, when doing this sort of UI switch. Or, use a `DialogFragment`, if you want to temporarily have something modal take over foreground input (as a dialog gets its own `Window`, if I understand correctly). Do not just paint a solid background and pretend that other widgets, now painted over, do not exist.

> Does this feature exist and I am not aware of it?

No, because fragments are not `ViewGroups` and therefore are not involved in managing the routing of touch events.

> And if not, should it?

IMHO, no, though you're welcome to file an issue for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. I was missing "to be clickable" after "Is setting the `ViewGroup` on the top most Fragment"; I edited my question, but I think you understood what I meant. So adding a `Fragment` on top of another is a big nono design-wise. For example, what if you have a `ListFragment` and your "details" page is also a `Fragment`, still one should call `replace()`? In order to get the `ListFragment` when the "back" button is pressed, calling `addToBackStack()` on the `FragmentTransaction` should do the trick, right?

Comment: @Emmanuel: "For example, what if you have a ListFragment and your "details" page is also a Fragment, still one should call replace()? " -- IMHO, yes. "calling addToBackStack() on the FragmentTransaction should do the trick, right?" -- yes.

Comment: So when do you use add?

Comment: @pdiddy: One case is to use `add()` when you know there is no fragment there already.

Comment: I feel like I might have a situation where the fragment should have consumed touches. I display images in a `ViewPager`. The user can view user comments on these images by tapping a button, which then slides up a `ListFragment` over the image. You can see the image through the translucent background of the ListFragment. The problem is, if the ListFragment has no data, you have an option of telling it to show a TextView with a message through `ListFragment.setEmptyText()`. But when this TextView is showing, all touches on where the ListView would have been gets passed to the ViewPager below it.

Comment: Although use replace is a good idea, but there are some situations, you'd better to use add. For example, I need to keep the backstack of all the fragments added to the activity, if I put the fragment with replace, when I press back key, the underlying fragment need to recreate(but it doesn't need to recreate with the add method), if the underlying fragment take lots of time, this is time consuming. and good idea?